# How can I use an SQL aggregate function on data I directly input at the command line (e.g. AVG(1, 2, 3))?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, aggregates

How can I enter multiple values into an aggregate function using just data I enter at the command line? Say, in Postgres, I run the following.

```
SELECT AVG(2);
```

I'll get the correct answer, but I can't find a way to enter multiple values, such as below, without getting an error.

```
SELECT AVG(1,NULL,2,3);
```

I've tried wrapping the numbers in various brackets but to no effect. What's the syntax I'm missing?

EDIT: Additionally, is there a way to include NULLs in the input?

Answer (score 1):

`AVG()` is an aggregate that operates over multiple *rows*. So you need to convert your comma separated list to one row per value to be able to use an aggregate like `avg()`. This could be done using e.g. `string_to_table`

```
select avg(num::numeric)
from string_to_table('1,2,3', ',') as x(num)
```

If you want to include a NULL value, you could add it to the list and convert it to null before casting it to a numeric value:

```
select avg(nullif(num, 'null')::numeric)
from string_to_table('1,2,3,4,null', ',') as x(num)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. Any idea how to add a NULL into the data and have it read as NULL?

Comment: The `AVG()` function by default _ignores_ `NULL` values.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm basically trying to simulate what SQL would do with different inputs. `AVG()` ignores `NULL` values, but I'm just using that as an example. I also need to be able to quickly test user-defined functions, which may or may not ignore `NULLs`.